# Any danger in linking `.git` directory for a build?

Tags: git

I'm setting up a general git deployment environment and I'm wondering if it's safe to set up a symlink to a `.git` directory?  By doing so, I'm hoping to be able to have seperate checkouts from the same repo without having to have to local copies of the history of a potentially large project.

Reasoning (pseudo-flow):

- web interface:

  - click "Deploy this commit to this server"
- server:

  - `ln -s ./deploy/.git ./build/.git`
  - `cd build`
  - `git fetch`
  - `git checkout some_commit`
  - `make`
  - if success:

    - `cd ..`
    - `mv build deploy`
    - `make deploy` // just reset nginx, apache, etc
  - if failure

    - alert user
    - wipe build directory, no harm done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `git-new-workdir`, a tool purpose-built for checking out multiple working directories from one .git directory.

Comment: git-new-workdir lives inside of the contrib/ folder in git. Many git installers will drop this folder somewhere on your disk, but if you don't have it you can clone the git.git repo and grab it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you clone a git repository locally, the `.git` directory will use hard links.  So you do not need to worry about space, at least for freshly cloned repositories.

```
$ du -chs repo/.git
 27M    repo/.git
 27M    total
$ git clone repo repo2
$ du -chs repo2/.git
 27M    repo2/.git
 27M    total
$ du -chs repo/.git repo2/.git
 27M    repo/.git
292K    repo2/.git
 27M    total
```

Since git caches information about the working copy, I am wary of symlinking the git directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to symlink your `.git` directory in the situation you describe.  (If you were using git in the directory with the symlinked `.git` it may get confusing however, because the index (or staging area) will be shared between the two.)

However, you don't need to do that for what you want - instead you can run the `git checkout` with the options `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` to tell git which repository directory and working tree to use.  For example:

```
mkdir /home/whatever/build/
git --git-dir=/home/foo/deploy/.git --work-tree=/home/foo/build/ checkout -f
```

I suggest (a) using absolute paths for both these options and (b) using either both of these options or neither of them, since otherwise the rules for which directories git actually uses can be confusing.